# YA Sci-Fi book series - Alien ships attack Earth and steal a family, download knowledge into their brains

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

A series of young adult books I read as a child in the 90s.

The basic storyline, I think, is that Earth came under attack by alien ships that feed off our photon cannons, and they steal a family, possibly a ruling family. They also steal the sun. The children who were taken away are made to grow rapidly, and they are put in a machine that downloads knowledge into their brain, making them learn fast. I vaguely remember one of the main characters being named Nova.

I remember them being quite thin books. One cover was one of the humans having an American football style helmet with spikes on it.

Comment: Can you please go to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and see if the prompts there provide more information that you could edit into your answer? Almost any detail will help, from whether you remember it as a paperback or hardback, to aspects of the cover, to series that you've read that you know are not this series even if they match up otherwise.

Comment: I remember them being quite thin books. One cover was one of the humans having an American football style helmet with spikes on

Comment: That's a good start.